# Exception Property [Id] Does Not Exist on This Collection Instance

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Why am I getting the exception:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Goods;
use App\Categories;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function categoryAction($latin_url){
        $category = Categories::where('latin_url', $latin_url)->get();
        var_dump($category->id); die;
        if ($category){
            $goods = Goods::where('category_id', $category->id)->get(); 
            return view('goods', ['goods' => $goods]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do a `dd` on `$category`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$category = Categories::where('latin_url', $latin_url)->get();
```

This returns you a Collection of results, no only one result. So there is no id attribute.
Use:

```
$category = Categories::where('latin_url', $latin_url)->first();
```

The above example does not work when there are 0 results, instead of this you can use:

```
$category = Categories::where('latin_url', $latin_url)->firstOrFail();
```

what will result in a HTTP 404 error when it does not exist